# Browser version detection in grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

please anyone could give information about the current browser detection in grails 2.2.4? For example facebook brings notification message,when an user uses the IE 7, that notifies to upgrade the browser.

thanks

Comment: soorry its  grails 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do browser detection, not just in Grails. However, since you asked for a Grails specific solution you may want to look at the Grails [Browser detection plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/browser-detection).

Using this plugin you can target specific browsers such as IE7 and display content only for those browsers. For example, on your page you could:

```
<browser:isMsie versionLower="8">
  You are using an old browser. Consider upgrading.
</browser:isMsie>
```

I suggest you read the documentation and perhaps even the source code for the plugin to understand how you can best apply it to your project.